# Computing using two dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to compute the following:

When there are

df1 (dataframe that has speed of characters(`char_speed`) of subtitle that starts at `start_time` and ends at `end_time`):

```
  char_speed  start_time  end_time
0         34           3        15
1         19          15        21
2          9          21        28
...
```

and

df2 (dataframe that has user's listening log that starts at `start_time` and ends at `end_time` with the `speed` that the user listened to at that interval):

```
  start_time  end_time  speed
0       9.23    20.929    1.0 
1        1.4     20.26    1.5
2       20.0      27.6   1.25
...
```

then compute the total character count during each interval:

```
  start_time  end_time  speed  total_char
0       9.23    20.929    1.0        
1        1.4     20.26    1.5
2       20.0      27.6   1.25
...
```

For example, `df2['total_char'].iloc[0]` would be

```
((15-9.23)*34) + ((20.929-15)*19)
```

as among time period of 9.23 ~ 20.929,

during 9.23 ~ 15, the speed would be 34,

during 15 ~ 20.929, the speed would be 19

and `df2['total_char'].iloc[1]` would be

```
(3-1.4)*0 + ((15-3)*34) + ((20.26-15)*19)
```

as among time period of 1.4 ~ 20.26,

during 1.4 ~ 3, the speed is not found in df1, so 0

during 3 ~ 15, the speed would be 34

during 15 ~ 20.26, the speed would be 19

I'm a newbie in Pandas and I've been recently mesmerized by how Pandas can be efficient in short and simple codings, but I'm not sure if there's a way to compute this in a short and simple coding. Right now, I can only think of an way to do it without utilizing Pandas functions: calling each row of `df2` and then searching through each row in `df1` and then compute it.

It would be helpful if you could tell me a way to efficiently code this using Pandas. Or any recommendation of functions would be helpful too!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Your equations don't seem to make much sense. Could you elaborate on how the `total_char` column is to be calculated?

Comment: @AnanayMital Thanks for pointing out! I've edited the question. Let me know if it still needs more clarification!

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't opposed to merging the dataframes then `apply` makes it easy.

```
df2 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, sort=False)

def speed_calc(row):
    return ((row['end_time1']-row['start_time1'])*row['char_speed']) + \
    ((row['end_time2']-row['end_time1'])*row['char_speed'])

df2['total_char'] = df2.apply(speed_calc, axis=1)
```

This would require you to adjust the header names.